# Wicket: How to use a DropDownChoice with a PropertyModel?

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm having trouble using PropertyModel with DropDownChoice. I need something that everytime the DropdownChoice changes, it compares the value and do something. This is what I am trying:

**Instantiating options stuff**

```
private String typeSelected = DEFAULT_TYPE_VALUE;

List<String> typeSelectChoices = new ArrayList<String>();

typeSelectChoices.add(DEFAULT_TYPE_VALUE);
typeSelectChoices.add(TextFactory.TYPE_VALUE_1;
typeSelectChoices.add(TextFactory.TYPE_VALUE_2);
```

**Instantiating DropDownChoice**

```
typeSelect = new DropDownChoice<String>(TYPE_SELECT_ID, 
                    new PropertyModel(this, "typeSelected"), typeSelectChoices);
```

**DropDownChoice onChange event**

```
typeSelect.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            System.out.println(typeSelected);
        }
    });
```

It always prints "Select", no matter what is the option selected. I also tried:

`System.out.println(typeSelect.getModel.getObject());`

Comment: What you need is `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour`. Without it the selected value isn't even submitted to the server. Hang on, this isn't the sequel of the question you asked yesterday, is it?

Comment: @biziclop Well, that worked... I guess I finally understand AjaxEventBehavior and AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. Basically, when info needs to be changed, AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior needs to be used so it submits to the server, right?

Sequel.. I guess you could say it is :P

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert here, but it looks like you need to reference the property of typeSelected and not typeSelected itself. So should look like this:

```
System.out.println(typeSelected.value);
```

As I said I am no expert so I am not sure that `.value` is the correct property but you should be able to figure that out from here.

Good luck!

---

UPDATED

This works in Javascript:

```
System.out.println(typeSelected.options[typeSelected.selectedIndex].value);
```

Comment: Tried using various properties, no success =/

Comment: Well actually that worked using JavaScript but I'd prefer using wicket and sticking to Java. But your input is valuable, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some other useful informations in the javadoc of method wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications of DropDownChoice.